# Compile Error: ByRef argument type mismatch creating new sheets

Tags: vba, excel

This code is defining a function that checks if a Sheet exists and returns a boolean value. The Sub is attempting to activate a workbook. It then checks a sheet (DataEntry) and iterates through the rows and checks if the teamname is already a sheet and if it isn't create a new sheet of that name and paste the data into that sheet. If the sheet does exist then it copies it into the existing sheet. Then it adds 1 to the match number so that when it goes to paste again as that determines what row it pastes the data in. But when I attempt to run it via a button on the sheet it gives me the byref argument type mismatch error.

Any thoughts on what might be wrong?

```
Function shtexists(shtname As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets(shtname)
    On Error GoTo 0
    SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function

Sub AddData()
    Workbooks("ScoutingDatabseMaster.xlsm").Activate
    Dim teamname As String
    Dim countery As Integer
    Dim matchnumber As Integer
    matchnumber = 1
    countery = 4
    teamname = Range("B4", "B" & countery)
    For countery = 4 To 9
        If shtexists(teamname) Then
            Worksheets("DataEntry").Range("C" & countery, "M" & countery).Copy
            Worksheets(teamname).Range("A" & matchnumber).Paste
        If teamname = "" Then
            MsgBox ("You forgot to Enter a Team Number!")
        Else
            Sheets.Add.Name = teamname
        End If
        Next countery
    matchnnumber = matchnumber + 1
    countery = 4
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `If shtexists(teamname) Then` when `teamname` is a `String`, while `Function shtexists(shtname As Worksheet) As Boolean`, `shtname As Worksheet`, this will raise a run-time error. `shtname` should be `String` as well.

Change your `Function` declaration to:

```
Function shtexists(shtname As String) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets(shtname)
    On Error GoTo 0
    shtexists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Or the other way - call it like this `shtexists(Worksheets("teamname"))`